# How do I get notification from Yodlee?

Tags: yodlee

We are integrating Yodlee api with our fin App and the provider account with Yodlee Api. How to get the notification from Yodlee API during or after account adding process completion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Webhooks](https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Webhooks) which will notify you about the progress or in case any user input required.